# Javascript syntax clear up

Tags: javascript, syntax

```
var me = new Object();
me.name = "Adithya";
me.age = 15;

for(var prop in me){
    console.log(me.prop); 

}
```

When I run this, it prints undefined. I don't understand why it doesnt print the value. When I type

```
console.log(prop);
```

it prints

```
name
age
```

Doesn't that mean that prop is a a field in me? So shouldn't me.prop(when prop is name) , work like me.name ?

Comment: [MDN - `for / in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Examples).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`prop` is a variable containing a string so you need to use `me[prop]` like this:

```
for(var prop in me){
    console.log(me[prop]); 
}
```

When your property name is in a variable, you need to use the `[prop]` syntax which in  your case would be `me[prop]`.

---

FYI, `me.prop` tries to access a property named `"prop"`.  It does not use the contents of the variable `prop`.  You can only use the dot syntax to access a property when the property name is a constant that is known at code parse time and when the characters in the property are legal to use in the Javascript dot syntax.  If it's in a variable (or if it contains characters like a `.` or a space), then you must use the bracket syntax which will fetch the contents of the variable and use that property name.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax you're looking for is `me[prop];`
`me.prop` is equivalent to `me['prop']` which is not what you want.
notice you didn't assign a value to `name` or  `age` before when you did `me.age` and `me.name`.